# How to change sbt version?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I would like to set the sbt version. I tried doing this by creating a file `project/build.properties` in my project and added the line

```
sbt.version=0.13.13
```

but IntelliJ tells me

> unused property

What am I to do to get IntelliJ to use a different sbt version?

Answer (score 3):

The line is correct. On project refresh, IntelliJ uses the sbt launcher which respects this property.

You probably just have another plugin which expects the property to be used somewhere within your code, so you can ignore the error message.